# Sign into meteor app with linkedin?

Tags: meteor, authentication, linkedin-api

I have completed writing the login flow for a user that clicks on a linkedin button on the homepage. It takes them to the linkedin endpoint. The user signs into their linkedin account, my app receives the `access_token` which I use to get the users linkedin profile details, such as they full name, email address.

Now, how can I use this linkedin data, i.e., the users unique linkedin access_token, email address in order for the user to be 'logged' into the meteor app?

I do not want to use another package, I want to build this myself. I would like help to understand what I can do from this point please.

Is this what I need to set up once I have the [access_token](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-oauth/oauth_client.js#L3)

```
Template.home.onRendered(function() {
})

Template.home.events({
   'click #li-logo': function() {
    Meteor.loginWithLinkedin();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid implementing your own login system from scratch in Meteor is going to be too time consuming for you. Let me point out that one of the main reasons to use Meteor is to take advantage of the ease of app development it provides and the vast collection of available packages.

Anyway, if you really want to learn the inner workings of the login system and how a properly coded linkedin sign-in should work, the best possible thing to do is to look at the source code of the [accounts-base](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-base) and [meteor-accounts-linkedin](https://github.com/PauliBuccini/meteor-accounts-linkedin/) packages.

Configure your linkedin package this way (place this in a server-only block or file):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  ServiceConfiguration.configurations.update(
    { "service": "linkedin" },
    {
      $set: {
        "clientId": "<your client id>",
        "secret": "<your secret>"
      }
    },
    { upsert: true }
  );
});
```

HTH!

Comment: I am looking at paulis package. After installing it, how do I get the button to show up and then access the data?

Comment: After installing the paulis linkedin package, you should now have a new method available that's called Meteor.loginWithLinkedin() . So create your own button on the page and make the button call this method (which can optionally take some arguments for asking specific permissions, for example) and a new user will be created in the Users collection automatically.

Comment: please look at my current code in the question. I understand the login flow to the credentials, but from the repo, I cant figure out where to put my api key.

Comment: the 'ServiceConfiguration' is not defined. I have installed the package "meteor add pauli:accounts-linkedin" and inserted the code into folder server>lib>startup.js

By the way, I think you left out a closed bracket at the end

Comment: Did you remember to add the accounts-base package as well?

Comment: yes I have accounts-base and this message is appearing. Do I need any other one for this package like 'meteor add service-configuration'?

Comment: Oh, silly me. You also need the service-configuration package.

Comment: No errors now, one last thing, where do I put that long url? I have to set my redirect uri, state, scope so it matches what is set up on my linkedin application account

Comment: I'm not completely sure what url you are talking about. But make sure you call the Meteor.loginWithLinkedin() from an actual button click, and not directly in the onRendered function, because linkedin will redirect back to the original page and it will get rerendered again, which will call the login function one more time. Anyway, this is turning into a very long comment section, so I'm going to let you have fun on your own. Please consider accepting my post if you think it was useful and if it answered your original question.

Comment: Its been very helpful so far, thank you. I will try and work on from here! Thanks!!